# Why do 'Infinity', 'null', 'NaN' and 'undefined' have inconsistent casing?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript the language constructs 'Infinity', 'null', 'NaN' and 'undefined' have inconsistent casing.

Is it historical, or is there an intent behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reasons are:

- In ECMAScript, types begin with uppercase:

  [Undefined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-undefined-type), [Null](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-null-type), [Boolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-boolean-type), [Number](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-type), [String](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-type), [Symbol](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-symbol-type), [Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type)
- Undefined and Null are two types which only have a single value, which has the same name as the type. But it would be too confusing if the case was also the same, so they used lowercase:

  [`undefined`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-undefined-value), [`null`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-null-value)
- [`NaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-nan) has this casing because it's a IEEE 754-2008 “Not-a-Number” value

  Not-a-Number ⟶ `NaN`
- [`Infinity`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-infinity) can begin with uppercase because there is no type called Infinity. I guess it could also begin with lowercase, but maybe they wanted something analogous to `NaN` (?)

Comment: I see, that makes more sense. It could be better, but I guess there's no changing it now as it would break basically every piece of code written in JS.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody knows. :-(

---

*(Original answer follows)*

Pure speculation, but…

- `null` <strike>and `undefined` are</strike> is a JavaScript keyword<strike>s</strike>, reflecting various "not a value" metawackery. All keywords I'm aware of are lowercase (c.f. `true`, `false`);
- `undefined` is a global property representing *even more* metawackery;
- `Infinity` and `NaN` are global properties reflecting IEEE floating-point sentinel values, and come straight (ish) from that third-party spec.

So I can see why distinct case conventions may have come into play here: apples and oranges.

To my mind, the real question is why those last two are not `Math.INFINITY` and `Math.NAN`.

Comment: Sigh. I wish undefined would really be a keyword.

Comment: @TamasHegedus: Aw, balls, is it not?

Comment: In Java it's `NaN` for no particular reason. Maybe that lower case `a` inspired `Infinity`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `undefined` is just an unmodifiable property on the global object

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, unfortunately it's not :(

Comment: I thought I had it with this. Now I reckon it's all just a load of unanswerable nonsense :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I couldn't agree more.

Comment: it should be better `Number.INFINITY` and `Number.NAN`.